# @RequestMapping in Spring Can't get secondary controller to take over

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've got this program I'm writing and I'm trying to get a secondary page to display once the user has logged in. My first screen is handled by the LoginInterfaceController as shown below.

```
@Controller
public class LoginInterfaceController{

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
@RequestMapping
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
    logger.info("Returning Login View");

    model.addAttribute(getLoginAttempt());

    return new ModelAndView("LoginView.jsp", model);
}

@ModelAttribute("LoginAttempt")
public LoginAttempt getLoginAttempt() {
    return new LoginAttempt();
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String validateLogin(@ModelAttribute("LoginAttempt") @Valid LoginAttempt loginDetails, 
        BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, 
        @RequestParam(value="username", required=true) String username, 
        @RequestParam (value="password", required=true) String password)
{
    String returnString;
    LoginAttempt checkLogin = new LoginAttempt(username, password);

    if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
        returnString = "LoginView.jsp";
    }
    else if((!checkLogin.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase("james") || !checkLogin.getPassword().equals("asdf123")))
    {
        returnString = "FailedLogin.jsp";
    }
    else
    {
        returnString = "redirect:" + "/ReferrerHome/";
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

Once the user is validated it should redirect them to the /ReferrerHome/ page.

My LeadInterfaceController has its request mappings set as follows

```
@Controller
public class LeadInterfaceController {

private LeadServiceClass leadService = new LeadServiceClass();
protected final Log4JLogger logger = new Log4JLogger();

@RequestMapping(value="/ReferrerHome/")
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
    logger.info("Returning Referrer Home View");

    model.addAttribute(getLead());
    model.addAttribute(getBrokerList());
    return new ModelAndView("home.jsp", model);
}

@ModelAttribute("Lead")
private Lead getLead() {
    return leadService.getNewLead();
}
@ModelAttribute("Broker")
private ArrayList<Broker> getBrokerList(/*Referrer referrer*/)
{
    return /*(ArrayList<Broker>)referrer.getBrokers() */ new ArrayList<Broker>();
}

@RequestMapping(value="ReferrerHome/home.jsp", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String validateLogin(@ModelAttribute("Lead") @Valid Lead leadInput, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model)            
{
    String returnString;
    if(leadInput.getLeadHomePhoneNumber() == null && 
            leadInput.getLeadWorkPhoneNumber() == null && 
            leadInput.getLeadMobilePhoneNumber() == null && 
            leadInput.getLeadEmail() == null){
        logger.info("HPhoneNum: " + leadInput.getLeadHomePhoneNumber());
        //code here to set an error state indicating that some contact information is required
    }
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
        returnString = "ReferrerHome/home.jsp";
    }
    else
    {
        leadService.getLeadDao().addLead(leadInput);
        returnString = "ReferrerHome/success.jsp";
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

However when the user is authenticated, the URL switches to /ReferrerHome/ but the LoginView.jsp is reloaded instead of the home.jsp being loaded.
The infuriating thing is that this was working 2 days ago, and I can't think what I did to cause it to break.

I have my LTSServlet.xml here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<jdbc:embedded-database id="LTSDatabase" type="HSQL" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.au.curtin" />
<import resource="*/WEB-INF/classes/com/au/curtin/leadtrackingsystem.xml" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="LTSDatabase" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="PersistenceAnnotationPostProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean id="hibernateExceptionTranslator"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
    id="PersistenceExceptionTranslator" depends-on="hibernateExceptionTranslator" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value="" />
</bean>
```

and my web.xml here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LTSServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LTSServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>LoginView.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  </web-app>
```

I am tearing my hair out trying to get this working.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no mapping to path in `validateLogin` (only request type). So that when you return "home.jsp" it is mapped to `validateLogin` and not to `@RequestMapping(value="ReferrerHome/home.jsp", method=RequestMethod.POST)`.

Try:
1. Return `ReferrerHome/home.jsp` in `LeadInterfaceController.handleRequest` instead of `home.jsp`.
2. Change mapping on `validateLogin`so that it contains path it is bound to (then you can have a descriptive error of your bug after redirection).

That should help.

You can also use debugger on DispatcherServlet and follow the flow (how the "login.jsp" page is chosen).

Comment: I've tried what you suggested. My problem is that if I put say @RequestMapping(value="/") in LoginInterfaceController, I get a 404 Not Found when I start my program (I'm using Tomcat so debug is out). Also, the LeadInterfaceController is never being run. Its not showing up in my logs. My LoginInterfaceController is run at the root of my application

Comment: You easily debug with tomcat using Eclipse, just start tomcat in debug mode. Btw. have you tried to change return value to "ReferrerHome/home.jsp" instead of "home.jsp" ?

Comment: Yes I have, it doesn't work because LeadInterfaceController doesn't actually get called. My biggest problem now is that I am 404'ing